# Cucumber environment variables

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber to run integration tests with Selenium. The location of the page to access varies slightly from environment to environment, so I'm looking for a while to store this information.

Is it possible to use Cucumber environment variables in Java? If so, where should I place the cucumber.yml file so that it is picked up? Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: I would use a properties file. e.g. qa.properties, stg.properties. I would take the environment name as an argument and load the corresponding properties file.

Comment: I'm not running it as a command-line app though, it's part of continuous integration. Currently we use various jars with configs that are dropped into the classpath, but obviously the tests aren't running as part of the main app so I don't think that would work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

LINGS is right about using properties files unique to the environment.  You have to deploy to get software into an environment so why not deploy the properties file appropriate to that environment? Another alternative is create a system environment variable.  On the CI server you might create something like WHICHPAGE='CIpage';

The cucumber.yml file has to be in a ".config subdirectory or config subdirectory of your current working directory".See [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml).

There are several Java Yaml projects listed [here](http://yaml.org/).  Pick one to use.

Comment: I know this question is oldish. But giving it an answer gets it off my answers:0 query result list.